# Query pages from ajax and pagination

Tags: php, jquery, pagination

I have a button that load results from remote server throught ajax :

1- Button click

2- Load content from remote throught ajax inside an element div#results

3- The result has pagination, that i want to ajaxify, and load the next result to the same place "div#results"

How do you handle this? i have a google map inside each results that i want to update after each pagination click.

Thank you for advice.

Comment: try using a variable keeping track of current page number with default page no as 1 and keep sending it to server through your ajax request, also try creating pagination on ajax return with current page number as selected

Comment: This is to implement on the button page or on the result page?

Comment: return both contents and pagination in same ajax response and render them on front .

Comment: Thank you, i resolved by return content and pagination and make another ajax call when click to a paginate link and passing page number ( item attribute) to the server.